# VBA Code to Create Lotus Notes Email - CC Emails Not Working

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013, lotus-notes

I have some VBA code that takes the various email parts as inputs and creates an email message in Lotus Notes, and sends it from a group mailbox.  It sends the email out to a recipient and CC recipients, and then leaves a copy of the message in the "Sent" box of a group email account.  I think the sent message in that box is sort of a dummy, as it is perhaps not the exact message as it was sent.

This works, and sends the message to the SendTo, and to the first CC address.  However, if I have a second CC address, it turns the ending of the second address into gibberish.  For example, if the SendTo is "mike@someemail.com", and the CC is "john@someemail.com, jim@someemail.com"...  in the Sent box it appears to have sent it to mike@someemail.com, and CC to john@someemail.com and jim@someemail.com.  However, the actual mail is only received by john, and the CC looks like this: "john@someemail.com, jim@pps.rte_to_v" and jim never gets the message.

On another message, the second CC ends up being jim@vwall11.com.  I haven't found a pattern to the gibberish it puts at the end of the CC line instead of the correct address.  It took us awhile to learn about the problem since it looks correct in the Sent mailbox.

Here's the code I'm using.  I'm changing the server names, etc, but all relevant code is intact.

```
Private Sub TestEmail()
Call EmailFromADT("mike@somemail.com", "john@somemail.com, jim@somemail.com", "test subject", "test message", _
                "", "", "", "")
End Sub

Function EmailFromADT(strSendTo As String, strCopy As String, strSubject As String, _
strText1 As String, strText2 As String, strText3 As String, _
strText4 As String, strText5 As String)

Dim notesdb As Object
Dim notesdoc As Object
Dim notesrtf As Object
Dim notessession As Object
Dim i As Integer


    Set notessession = CreateObject("Notes.Notessession")

''''''''Group Mailbox'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Set notesdb = notessession.GetDatabase("servername", "mailin\notesaddr.nsf")
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    'Open the mail database in notes
    If notesdb.IsOpen = True Then
    'Already open for mail
    Else
    notesdb.OPENMAIL
    End If

    Set notesdoc = notesdb.CreateDocument
    Call notesdoc.ReplaceItemValue("Subject", strSubject)
    Set notesrtf = notesdoc.CreateRichTextItem("body")
    Call notesrtf.AppendText(strText1 & vbCrLf & strText2 & vbCrLf & strText3 & vbCrLf & strText4 & vbCrLf & strText5)
    notesdoc.SendTo = strSendTo
    notesdoc.CopyTo = strCopy
    notesdoc.from = UserName()

''''''''Group Mailbox'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    notesdoc.principal = "Group Team"
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    notesdoc.BlindCopyTo = strBCC

    Call notesdoc.Save(True, False)
    notesdoc.SaveMessageOnSend = True
    Call notesdoc.Send(False, strSendTo)
    Set notessession = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have multiple values in an item in a Document, you need to use an array.

Try this:

```
dim varCopyTo as Variant
varCopyTo = Split( strCopyTo, "," )

call notesDoc.Replaceitemvalue( "CopyTo", varCopyTo )
```

You could also write `notesDoc.CopyTo=varCopyTo`, but it is better (more secure, slightly better performance) to use ReplaceItemValue.

In addition you should add `Call notesDoc.ReplaceItemValue("Form", "Memo" )` after creating the document, so that the server/client does not have to "guess" what kind of document you are creating.

Answer (score 2):

`notesdoc.CopyTo` wants an array, not a comma-delimted string on the right hand side of the assignment. Each element in the array should be an individual address.  By passing in a comma-delimited string, you're essentially passing in a single invalid address as far as Notes and Domino are concerned. I'm not entirely sure why that's being transformed in the peculiarly random way that it is, but I am sure it's definitely not going to be right that way.

And better than using the shorthand form (notesdoc.CopyTo = ...) for this code, you should probably be using Call `notesdoc.ReplaceItemValue`, like you do with the Subject, but passing in an array there.